# Java Script to Validate Saturday and Sunday

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html textbox in php page which will usually get date as Input.

I want to make sure that textbox won't accept the Saturday and Sunday.

So I use the following code:

```
if ($filing_date_from != "")
{
    var d = filing_date_from.getDay();
    if (d == '6' || d == '0')
    {
        alert('Dont Enter Sat/Sun');
    }
}
```

But this code is not working. I didn't get alert when I enter the Sat/Sun.

Comment: @Jenz: please don't change the capitalisation of variable/property names in code from questions, especially in programming languages where variable names are case-sensitive (such as JavaScript). Thanks!

Comment: I didn't formatted the code. It was already done.

Comment: @Jenz: according to the edit summary you changed `getDay` to `getday`:  http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22318066/2

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code since it was already formatted well. When I edited, it may be like getday only. I don't remember that.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing $ sign from following line of your code

var d=**filing_date_from**.getDay();

should be

var d=**$filing_date_from**.getDay();

Remember $filing_date_from should be date object not the string

Comment: How can i use a php var in javascript.. is that possible.?

Comment: In javascript code you can use
var jsvariable = <?php echo $php_variable;?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
/*
* This function returns the Day Name
* INPUT :    appDate : Date in mm-dd-yyyy format
*   seperator: the date seperator
*/

function getDayName(appDate, seperator){


               // Name of the days as Array
               var dayNameArr = new Array ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday", "Saturday");
               var dateArr = appDate.split(seperator); // split the date into array using the date seperator
               var month = eval(dateArr[0]); 
               var day = eval(dateArr[1]);
               var year = eval(dateArr[2]);
              // Calculate the total number of days, with taking care of leapyear 
              var totalDays = day + (2*month) + parseInt(3*(month+1)/5) + year + parseInt(year/4) - parseInt(year/100) + parseInt(year/400) + 2;
              // Mod of the total number of days with 7 gives us the day number
              var dayNo = (totalDays%7);
              // if the resultant mod of 7 is 0 then its Saturday so assign the dayNo to 7
              if(dayNo == 0){
                   dayNo = 7;
              }
            return dayNameArr[dayNo-1]; // return the repective Day Name from the array


}
</script>

</head>
<body>
             <!-- // Date in mm-dd-yyyy format; "-" is the date seperator we can change as per the date seperator format -->


             <input type="button" value="Click Me Date(10-12-2009) seperator(-)" onClick='javascript:alert(getDayName("10-12-2009", "-"));' />
            <input type="button" value="Click Me Date(10.13.2009) seperator(.)" onClick='javascript:alert(getDayName("10.13.2009", "."));' />
           <input type="button" value="Click Me Date(10/14/2009) seperator(/)" onClick='javascript:alert(getDayName("10/14/2009", "/"));' />


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

May following example help you exactly what you want

```
<?php
  $date = '2014-03-08';
?>
<script language="javascript">
  var $filing_date_from = new Date('<?php echo $date;?>');
  if($filing_date_from!="")
  {
    var d=$filing_date_from.getDay();
    if(d=='6' || d=='0')
    {
     alert('Dont Enter Sat/Sun');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Let me check... :-) @Awais